# C - get char in while and push to stack

Tags: c, stack, runtime-error

I am trying to create a stack from user input. In order to stop inserting char's, I am asking the user to enter `c`. When the user enters `c`, I am getting an error saying `Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'stack' was corrupted.`

This is my code:

```
#define N 10

typedef char stackType;
typedef struct {
    int top;
    stackType S[N];
} stack;

void createStack(stack *ps) {
    ps->top = -1;
}

int push(stackType data, stack *ps) {
    if (ps->top < N - 1) {
        ps->top++;
        ps->S[ps->top] = data;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void Ex01() {
    stack *stack;
    createStack(&stack);
    char input;
    printf("Please enter letters. Enter 'c' top stop:\n");
    scanf(" %c", &input);
    while (input != 'c') {
        push(input, &stack);
        scanf(" %c", &input);
    }
}

int main() {
    Ex01();
}
```

Comment: It should have been `createStack(stack);`, you are passing the double pointer

Comment: Listen to the compiler warnings and treat them as errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use the statement

```
createStack(&stack);
```

then `stack` should have been declared as `stack stack` without the `*`

that way it would be allocated on the your program's stack.

in the matter of `stack *stack` you're passing an uninitialized pointer to the function `createStack` which can lead to your program crashing.

if you still want to use `stack *stack` you have to dynamically allocate memory for that pointer i.e. using `malloc`.